# Gluten-free replacement to coat something with before roasting, to obtain crust

Tags: roasting, crust, gluten-free

A recipe calls for coating (slightly cooked) fennel bulbs in flour before roasting them, presumably to obtain a bit of a crust. Is there anything I could coat them with that is gluten-free?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rice flour should work well for this; it produces very crispy crusts.

Comment: Doesn't rice flour also contain gluten?

Comment: No. Rice generally thought of as a good gluten free alternative. Brown rice contains something like .02 of gluten so some highly intolerant people can only have white. I emphasis that this is rare though.

Comment: @nunu: thanks for the correction. It seems I learn something new every few hours, and unlearn something wrong every day.

Answer (score 8):

I like nuts that are finely chopped, kinda like bread crumbs. Almond flour will perhaps work as well.

Answer (score 7):

The last time I made "breaded" chicken, I had some spare lentils leftover and decided to pulse them in the food processor and try using them (not quite to a fine powder, but closer to that than whole).  The result was delicious, a little bit of a nutty flavor, and a great crunch.

Comment: +1 for a cool, off the beaten path idea. Did the wife consider it a vegetable? ;)

Comment: @yossarian - HA! I didn't think to ask, but I bet she did :) and it must have been pretty good because she asked me to make it again the next week!

Comment: This sounds delicious! Were the lentils cooked or raw when you pulsed them?

Comment: They were still raw - which is why I decided to take them down to a size that was as close to a powder as I could without being an actual full-on powder (though I suspect a powder would work just as well, maybe with just a little less crunch)

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using potato flour. It gives a coating sort of like the outside of a chip (french fry).

Comment: And for the cases where you're replacing breadcrumbs instead of flour, you can crush up potato chips (but use the thicker cut ones, like the ripple cut ones)

Answer (score 3):

Grits, which is to say coarsely-ground corn. Also try *masa*, which is very finely-ground corn. You can find *masa* in Mexican grocery stores.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what I usually use at home is chickpea flour.
It has a neutral flavour, generally, and gives a nice brown coat to my pakoras.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use corn starch.  It's gluten free and I use it as part of (although not all of) my fried chicken coating for extra crispiness.

Almond meal is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Bean flour, usually from lentils is a very good gluten free replacement for many things (except in baking). It's very popular in a lot of Indian food.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick is correct. Gram flour (milled from chickpeas) is used extensively for 'crunch' with fried stuff. It does have a taste of its own which although tasty, doesn't necessarily go with *everything*. But its definitely worth a try.

Its also a very good alternative to facial scrub cosmetics.

Some links:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/chickpea_flour
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_flour